# Using QTimer for displaying timer

Tags: c++, qt

I created a class called aTimer which inherits from `QTimer`. I want to be able to store the time elapsed into a variable called `TimeElapsed` of type `int`. I then want to have the timer automatically started when the main window opens and for it to display the time elapsed therein.

I think I'm using the wrong timer, and I am quite confused as to which tools to be using within `Qt` because there are different ways of handling time. Suffice it to say that I want a stop-watch kind of module that allows me to start and stop time manually without a cap (or an interval with the case of Timer). How shall I proceed? So far, attempts to use `QTimer` are fruitless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need a derived class for this task. I'd probably use a [`QTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtimer.html) and a [`QElapsedTimer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html).

Create them in your main window constructor and set the QTimers interval according to how often the time should be updated. Also connect its `timeout()` signal to a function updating the displayed value. In this function you can get the elapsed time from the QElapsedTimer and update the display.

```
// *.h
QTimer* timer;
QElapsedTimer *eltimer;

// *.cpp
constructor(){
    this->timer = new QTimer(this);
    this->timer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(this->timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update_ui()));
    this->timer->start();

    this->eltimer = new QElapsedTimer(this);
    this->eltimer->start();
}

SLOT update_ui(){
    qint64 msecs_elapsed = this->eltimer->elapsed();
    // Insert value into ui object
}
```

Of course you can create some buttons to `start()` and `stop()` the `QTimer`

Comment: Thanks! It works, except I don't want milliseconds so I divided the variable by 1000.